# FluentNHibernate Mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I have same classes:

```
public class Card : EntityBase
{
    private IList<Accident> accidents;
    public Card()
    {
        Accidents = new List<Accident>();
    }

    public virtual IList<Accident> Accidents
    {
        get { return accidents; }
        set { value = accidents; }
    }

    public virtual void AddAccident(Accident accident)
    {
        Accidents.Add(accident);
        accident.Card = this;
    }

}

public class Accident : EntityBase
{
    public Accident(){ 
    }
    public virtual Card Card { get; set; }     

}
```

And their mappings

```
public class AccidentMap : ClassMap<Accident>
{
    public AccidentMap()
    {
        Table("ACCIDENT");
        Id(x => x.Id).Not.Nullable().Column("ID_ACCIDENT");
        References(x => x.Card).Column("ID_CARD").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}
```

When I trying to save Accident I have NullReferenceException in Accidents.Add(accident). Why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`set { value = accidents; }`
Should be
`set { accidents = value; }`

Comment: Oops, I don't noticed. Thanks

Comment: Partially. Now I have conflict with foreign key in table "CARD" column "ID_CARD". What's wrong?